# Hand writing a SQL query with a has_many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

For reasons out of my control, I need to hand write a SQL query by hand in MySQL.

My models are:

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :buildings
  has_many :floors, through: :buildings
  has_many :workspaces, through: :floors
end

class Workspace < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :floor
end

class Floor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :workspaces
end
```

I need to order my Survey's based on how many workspaces it has.

In Rails code I can do something like: `@survey.workspaces.size` and that will get my the amount of workspaces the `@survey` has.

Given this SQL query:

```
SELECT `surveys`.* 
FROM `surveys` 
ORDER BY surveys.workspaces.size asc 
LIMIT 10 
OFFSET 0
```

How can I write the query by hand that orders based on workspace amount?

Comment: I'd use a named scope here...

Comment: I would too, but I literally need to craft this query by hand due to design constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Add a scope to the model. Find the AR which results in the wanted answer. Add `to_sql` to that ActiveRecord to get the needed SQL-Code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whatever you want to mix SQL with Rails or just SQL alone. The pure SQL would be:

```
SELECT s.id, count(w.id) AS workspaces_count
FROM surveys s LEFT JOIN workspaces w ON s.id = w.survey_id
GROUP BY s.id
ORDER BY 2
```

If you want to add another columns from Survey then you need to also add them to GROUP BY.